# Is it legit to use macros from `cstdarg` to access normal function arguments?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I'm writing a template container (similar to tuple). Now I need to create a constructor for it. So if I define it like this:

```
template <typename ...P> class Container
{
    /*blah-blah*/
public:
    Container(P...)
    {
        /*blah-blah*/
    };
};
```

I will get comma-separated anonymous arguments after pack expansion. It's probably impossible create names for them, so I'm thinking about using macros from 'cstdarg' to access them. Of course, I need to create a non-templated first argument to use them, but the question is:

Is it legit to use stuff from 'cstdarg' to access normal arguments (just usual arguments, not ones that were used with `...` function parametr)?

Comment: This sounds like a XY problem for me. Why would you want to do so? I don't get it. And no it's not legit, works completely different and not with variadic templates.

Comment: not every type can be passed to `...` legally

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have a tuple-like class and I need a constructor for it. I want to initialize contents of the class with arguments of the constructor.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat You can forward arguments to `std::tuple` it's a variadic template itself.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I want to create this template without any external classes, because I want to learn more about how the templates work. Looks like `std::tuple` have the same constructor I want; I'll look at tuple implementation and will try to make a similar constructor. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `cstdarg` parameters may be passed by a different ABI convention than named parameters (including parameter packs). In general, `cstdarg` doesn't support C++ types that are not standard-layout (i.e., C-like), and it shouldn't be used in C++ code.